# about java-RMI concept

Tags: java, rmi

my prof. asked me execute a RMI program.
the compilation of client and server programs are perfect.it didn't generate any error.
but when i give 'rmic implementation class-name',it shows that no class found.

i was thought that,the implementation program will be automatically compiled when client and server program is compiled.After compiling those two,i can find the implementation  program class file along with the client and server class files in the stored location .but when i try to generate the client stub and server skeleton,it shows that "implementation class  not found."

please help me to find the implementation program's class file .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official tutorial for this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html